# Creating multiple / multinode properties in class

Tags: c#, class, properties, declaration

I would like to understand and make my own classes in the way like the common rectangle:

```
Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle();
Size s = r1.Size;
int size = r1.Size.Width;
```

I don't want to use methods, just simple property values.

```
public partial class Rectangle
{
    private Size _size;
    public Size Size
    {
        get { return _size; }
        set { _size = value; }
    }
}
```

So how to create the Width, Height, etc. properties?

And if i would like to create longer chain? e.g.:

```
r1.Size.Width.InInches.Color.
```

etc.

Comment: The Width and Height are properties of the `Size` structure, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.size(v=vs.110).aspx)
To make chains of methods it's usually referred to as Fluent Interface or Syntax, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#C.23) for more info.

Comment: Create nested objects, then nested objects inside them, etc.

Comment: @amura.cxg Well, fluent is a little different.  Fluent typically returns the original object so you can chain multiple calls - this is just plain ol' OOP encapculation.

Comment: Why not use "public Size Size { get; set; }" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you'll find yourself saying: I knew it.

Class properties can be associations with other classes:

```
public class Size 
{
    public Size(double width, double height)
    {
        Width = width;
        Height = height;
    }
    public double Width { get; }
    public double Height { get; }
}
```

Now you'll be able to get rectangle's size as follows: `rect1.Size.Width`.

About providing the size unit, I wouldn't create an `InInches` property, but I would create an enumeration:

```
public enum Unit
{
    Inch = 1,
    Pixel
}
```

...and I would add a property to `Size` as follows:

```
public class Size 
{
    public Size(double width, double height, Unit unit)
    {
        Width = width;
        Height = height;
        Unit = unit;
    }

    public double Width { get; }
    public double Height { get; }
    public Unit Unit { get; }
}
```

...and if you need to perform conversions, you could easily implement them in `Size` too:

```
public class Size 
{
    public Size(double width, double height, Unit unit)
    {
        Width = width;
        Height = height;
        Unit = unit;
    }

    public double Width { get; }
    public double Height { get; }
    public Unit Unit { get; }

    public Size ConvertTo(Unit unit)
    {
        Size convertedSize;

        switch(unit) 
        {
            case Unit.Inch:
                // Calc here the conversion from current Size
                // unit to inches, and return
                // a new size
                convertedSize = new Size(...);
                break;


            case Unit.Pixel:
                // Calc here the conversion from current Size 
                // unit to pixels, and return
                // a new size
                convertedSize = new Size(...);
                break;

            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException("Unit not supported yet");
                break;
        }

        return convertedSize;
    }
}
```

What you call *chain* is what in object-oriented programming is called [*composition*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition).

Thus, you can associate Size with other class, and associate another class to the other one, and so on...

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer(s), both answer are right and helpful, and double thanks for the Size ConvertTo idea!